# Flutter / Moor getting dynamic function return type error when trying to build my data model

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I am using MOOR for data persistence in my Flutter app.

dependencies in pub `spec.yaml file`

```
path: ^1.8.0
json_annotation: ^4.0.1
moor_flutter: ^4.0.0
intl: ^0.17.0
moor: ^4.4.1

dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
moor_generator: ^4.4.1
build_runner: ^2.0.6
```

My `moor_db.dart` file

```
import 'package:moor_flutter/moor_flutter.dart';
part 'moor_db.g.dart';

 class CalendarDayMoor extends Table {
 IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement().call();
 DateTimeColumn get date => dateTime()();
 }
```

I get the following error for both properties

```
  A value of type 'Column<int>' can't be returned from the function 'id' 
 because it has a return type of 'dynamic Function()'.dartreturn_of_invalid_type
```

Here is a picture of what I see for reference. To the best of my understanding, this should be working.  Any ideas? has anyone run into this? what could be happening? what am I missing?

[image: Error on both properties]

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have fixed itself by morning.

Steps I took:

- Run flutter upgrade, to make sure you are using the latest DART SDK (that seemed to be part of the issue)
- restart your machine and VSCode
- remember to run `flutter pub get` so you have added all your dependencies

Best of luck!